# SPSiteDataQuery: Filtering Content Types in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spsitedataquery

In SharePoint 2007 executing a `SPSiteDataQuery` with filter for content types worked as expected.

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>
    <Value Type='Text'>SomeContentType</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

In SharePoint 2010 the same query only returns items from one list.
A possible workaround would be to filter on the content type id. A "BeginsWith" operator has to be used, since the "list content type" inherits from the "site content type":

```
<Where>
  <BeginsWith>
    <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeID'/>
    <Value Type='Text'>SomeContentTypeId</Value>
  </BeginsWith>
</Where>
```

But this would match all items with this content type or with any inherited content type. Which is not what I want.

Does anyone know how to create a `SPSiteDataQuery` with content type filter?

Comment: I like the beauty of being able to select all inherited content types. Why do you select the ID by using `BeginsWith` instead you can select the specific content type or even `EndsWith`?!

Comment: There isn't an `EndsWith` element in CAML, is it?

Comment: You're right, sorry. But `Contains` does exist.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?
Something weird which I've witnessed using the content type name is as follows :

Comment: Hierarchy of `Home > News > multiple year webs`. Content types are located within year webs! A query at the root returns nothing, where as a query at the 'News' level does return something. So It can do cross list!? just not at the root level. BUG!?

Comment: There has to be an issue with the migrated content. A new site using the same content types with same hierarchy can query from the root level and get results. This is weird. For now may revert to ID though since that at least works! I must be experiencing the same issue you had. Has to be some corruption somewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (see the **computed** value type):

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>
    <Value Type='Computed'>SomeContentType</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```